# C# - Seperate class return values, stored in listBoxItems, from listBoxItems to seperate labels

Tags: c#, string, class, listbox, return

```
public class newStudent_class
        {
            public String firstName;
            public String secondName;
            public DateTime birthday;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return firstName+ " " + secondName + ", " + birthday.ToString("dd.MMM.yyy");
            }
        }
```

The class creates newStudents (first/second Name, and b-day)
a button click is storing those values in a listBox

```
listBox1.Items.Add(myNewStudent);
```

The problem is here:
I want listBox1.SelectedItem to be separted by firstname, secondname and b-day
and store them in lblFirstName.Text = "..."
lblSecondName.Text = "..." and the same for b-day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add an event handler for SelectedIndexChanged of your listbox.  Then in your event handler you can cast the selected item to your class type and plop those values in your labels.

```
void MyListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newStudent = myListBox.SelectedItem as newStudent_class;
    if (newStudent != null)
    {
        lblFirstName.Text = newStudent.firstName;

        // etc...
    }
}
```